# Unable to deploy ASP.NET MVC website

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, deployment

In order to check whether my ASP.NET MVC application will run on my host. I tried deploying an ASP.NET MVC application with just one controller and one view. I have copied all the necessary files in the bin directory which are as following:

- Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure
- System.Web.Helpers
- System.Web.Mvc
- System.Web.Razor
- System.Web.WebPages.Deployment
- System.Web.WebPages
- System.Web.WebPages.Razor.

Other than above files, following files are included

[image]
However, I still get an 404 error. This is the URL http://jan-lokpal.rdinvent.com/Home/Index

What else do I need to copy or am I missing something? This is a windows hosting account only.

I tried contacting the support but they are not available.

Comment: You failed to mention which files you included from your project

Comment: @jgauffin, I have updated the post with the other files

Comment: did you copy the project DLL from your binfolder?

Comment: yaa , i did that....sorry i forgot to mention that because i didnt thought it was necessary since one is supposed to copy the project binary :-P

Comment: Is it necessary to have Asp.net 4.0 installed on the server to run Asp.net MVC websites ??

Comment: MVC3 requires .NET 4. We can't assume that everyone copies all project files. So if you don't say, we'll have to ask.

Comment: hmm.....I just had a chat with them and they said they have .NET 4 installed.....

Comment: As @Aliostad pointed out: Are your application pool running ASP.NET 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkpoints:

1) Make sure application pool runs ASP .NET 4.0

2) Make sure web.config has this line:

```
<system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        ....
```

Comment: The second point is checked. My web.config file has already got this entry

Comment: But i am not sure about the first thing.....All i have is the access to file structure and some basic settings in control panel for the hosting. From there i cant say if they have asp.net 4.0 installed or not